# Find datetime row closest to rounded datetime with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns.
The first one is "rounded_time" and the second column is "time".

In case there is a duplicate row for "rounded_time", I want to keep only the row whose "time" is closest to "rounded_time"

For example,

| actual_time | time |
| --- | --- |
| 09:00:00 | 08:59:02 |
| 09:00:00 | 09:00:00 |

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {
    'time_index': ['2022-06-06 08:59:04', '2022-06-06 09:00:00', '2022-06-06 09:30:00'],
    'time': [1, 2, 3],
    'rounded_datetime': ['2022-06-06 09:00:00', '2022-06-06 09:00:00', '2022-06-06 09:29:39']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time_index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_index'])
df['rounded_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['rounded_datetime'])
```

In the picture above,  I want to remove the first row because both the first and second row have rounded_time "09:00" but the second row's "time" is closer to the corresponding "rounded_time." (You can be assured that there are not multiple rows with same values for "time" column). Also each column has type datetime64.

I checked other posts on stack overflow, but they didn't help much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new column, which is the absolute difference between the datetime and the rounded datetime, and then find the minimum for each rounded value.

```
(df.assign(diff=(abs(df['time_index'] - df['rounded_datetime']))) # create the difference column (we use the absolute value because we don't care which direction the difference is in)
   .sort_values('diff')
   .groupby('rounded_datetime') # group each time_index by the rounded_datetime, and get the first for each rounded_datetime, which is going to be the minimum, because of sorting
   .first()
   .drop('diff', axis=1)) # drop the diff column

     rounded_datetime          time_index  time
0 2022-06-06 09:00:00 2022-06-06 09:00:00     2
1 2022-06-06 09:29:39 2022-06-06 09:30:00     3
```

Comment: Better than sort+groupby.first you can use groupby.idxmin for slicing.;)

Answer (score 0):

#### Following the idea of the image

You can just sort_values so in the dataframe by those two columns, remember that the function by default is in ascending order, after that just drop the duplicates (it keeps first by default).
If you want to change/update your dataframe use "inplace=True" in both functions.

```
df.sort_values(by=['rounded_time', 'time'], inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(keep='last',inplace=True)
```

If you don't want to change/update your dataframe just write a new one

```
new_df=df.sort_values(by=['rounded_time', 'time'], inplace=True)
new_df=df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Comment: But since you can have like times like 9:14 be rounded to 9, as 8:52 to 9.
Probably is good to check for the absolute number of timedelta between the "rounded_time" and "time", sort by it, then drop th duplicate, something in the way Mark, did it in the answer above